# MPI test program gets stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c++, openmpi

The library PETSc runs some test programs during configuration while checking the environment. One of those test programs is the following program (reduced by two relative headers):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main() {
    int size;
    int ierr;
    MPI_Init(0,0);
    ierr = MPI_Type_size(MPI_LONG_DOUBLE, &size);
    if(ierr || (size == 0)) exit(1);
    MPI_Finalize();
    ;
    return 0;
}
```

Configuration fails, due to a timeout. When debugging the program, it gets stuck at the line `MPI_Init(0, 0);`, even though this line should be perfectly legal. I am using OpenMPI 2 with G++ 9.2.1, running on OpenSUSE TW.
The program is compiled using

```
mpicxx -O0 -g mpi_test.cpp -o mpi_test
```

Comment: Maybe int *argc can not be 0? Just a guess

Comment: According to https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-2.0/node43.htm `Conforming implementations of MPI are required to allow applications to pass NULL for both the argc and argv arguments of main`, thus that line should be valid.

Comment: Some MPI implementations examine the environment to see how many processes to expect and how to communicate with them.  Perhaps it’s waiting on fellows that do not exist to reach their own `MPI_Init`?

Comment: @DavisHerring: How could I check that?

Comment: @arc_lupus: Just guesses: build the program yourself.  If it fails, `strace` it; if it works, compare the environment to that of the failing version.

Comment: Could you add details on how you configure PetSc, and how you compile and run the isolated test? I am not able to reproduce the hang with the software and system that you mention.

Comment: @jacob: I added the compilation line. After testing the code on a second system (running OpenSUSE TW), I could not reproduce the hang there either. Thus, I assume something in my MPI installation must be buggy.

Comment: @jacob: Did some more testing. It worked fine with OpenMPI 3, but fails with OpenMPI 2. Is there some correlation?